# Android ListView cutting off items wider than the first item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a Listview inside of a HorizontalScrollView. The listview holds file paths, and the horizontal scroll view is intended to eliminate the need to wrap the longer paths.

Everything is working exactly as desired with the exception that any items longer than the first item in the listview are being cut of at the length of the first item (whatever the width of the first item, none of the other items will scroll past that width).

Here is the section of the layout that is giving me trouble:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutListView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spFileTypes">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lvItems"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

[image: listview issue screenshot]

The image is scrolled all the way to the right. The third item is cutting off ".php". I have tried this with long and short file names, lists of many (upper double digits) and lists with just a few, in each case, it seems the width limit is dependent of the width of the first item.

Whenever the lists changes, it always limits its width to whatever the first element is.

The desired behavior is to have it match the width of the widest item.

I've googled my heart out, dug through the official documentation, and I'm stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your HorizontalScrollView has a layout_weight = 1 and the second child in the LinearLayout doesn't. You should add the weight to the TextView or remove it from the ListView. Hope it's help.

Comment: I'll make a note of that, but the TextView is showing up in the layout exactly as desired (the screenshot is cropped just to show the cut off behavior specifically)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wrapping the ListView in HorizontalScrollView, try this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>
```

Comment: Yep, listview should not be a child of any scrollview. It can lead to wierd behavior.

Comment: Not sure why but when I change the code to that, it wraps the strings, making them a bit hard to read. I'm not getting any scrollbars on the screen either (I assume because they are wrapping?) Could this be an issue with the TextView for each individual list item?